# Работа с генераторами python

Tags: python, генераторы

Мне нужно написать некий аналог chain, который может вытаскивать из генераторов поочередно по одному значению (генераторы лежат в списке  arg_list) и выводить в один список

Я попробовала так:

```
list(map(lambda *i: i, *arg_list))
```

Однако это работает только для генераторов одинакового размера, а мне нужно если один заканчивается, продолжать выводить значения из других

Что здесь можно придумать?

Comment: itertools.chain(*iterables)  вам не подойдёт ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

arg_list = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6]]

print([
    x
    for tup in zip_longest(*arg_list)
    for x in tup
    if x is not None
])
```

```
[1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5]
```

Или вот более универсальный вариант, если среди элементов может встречаться `None`

```
arg_list = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6, None]]
fill = object()

print([
    x
    for tup in zip_longest(*arg_list, fillvalue=fill)
    for x in tup
    if x is not fill
])
```

```
[1, 3, 6, 2, 4, None, 5]
```

Comment: тоже пробовала с zip_longest но совсем забыла о поле fillvalue, без которого получались ненужные None, спасибо большое!